# Задача определения объектов на изображении

Tags: python, tensorflow

Пытаюсь разобраться с определением объектов, расположенных на картинке. Например, все, что связано с алкоголем (рюмки, бокалы, бутылки и так далее).
За основу взял статью со страницы [How to play Quidditch using the TensorFlow Object Detection API](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-play-quidditch-using-the-tensorflow-object-detection-api-b0742b99065d)

Для решения задачи использую TensorFlow в Google Colaboratory.

Разобрался с картинками, создал датасет. Запустил в Google colaboratory. В итоге ничего не распознается. Подумал, что мало картинок, мало шагов для тренировки. Тогда просто воспроизвел тот самый пример, который по ссылке. Для того, чтобы чужой пример начал распознавать, хватило всего 4000 шагов для тренировки. Я даже чужой пример упростил немного: я перетренировал его всего на 27 картинках. И все равно он отлично распознавал свои объекты после 4000 шагов обучения.
Теперь я вместо чужих объектов тренировал на своих. И в результате ничего не распознается. Уже прошел около 20 000 шагов. Результата нет. Все, что сделал, это заменил snitch на рюмки в датасете. Убедился, что аннотации делаю корректно, датасет правильный. 
Предполагаю, что мало шагов. Или мало картинок. Но почему-то же чужие объекты при точно таких же условиях распознаются же! 
Я новичок во всем этом и пока еще не знаю, в какую сторону копать.
Кто-нибудь может подсказать, **на что обратить внимание**, что учитывать при тренировке. В каком разрешении должны быть картинки для датасета? Каких размеров?
И в процессе тренировки кидается плавающая ошибка:

> INFO:tensorflow:Error reported to Coordinator: , mscoco_train.record; Input/output error
>      [[Node: parallel_read/ReaderReadV2_2 = ReaderReadV2[_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](parallel_read/TFRecordReaderV2_2, parallel_read/filenames)]]
>   INFO:tensorflow:Error reported to Coordinator: , mscoco_train.record; Input/output error
>      [[Node: parallel_read/ReaderReadV2_2 = ReaderReadV2[_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](parallel_read/TFRecordReaderV2_2, parallel_read/filenames)]]

Понятно, что она связана с вводом/выводом, но она же возникает где-то на серверах google. Может банальный таймаут срабатывает и  возникает эта ошибка, связанная с дисковыми операциями. Как ее обойти, пока тоже не знаю. Экспортирую текущий граф, а потом продолжаю тренировать. Правильно ли делаю, не знаю.
Заранее спасибо за помощь!

Comment: обратитесь к своим картинкам, убедитесь, что они соответствуют условиям Google colaboratory

Comment: ок, спасибо за подсказку, посмотрю!

Comment: Достойная задача! (+1) Есть некоторые идеи, но сначала надо попролбовать самому... Вы можете запаковать всю директорию с проектом, включая ваш дата сет и выложить на какой-нибудь файло-обменник, чтобы можно было попробовать?

Comment: Я, к сожалению не имею права выкладывать исходники, так как я проект делаю не для себя, я наемный работник и выкладывать любые наработки строжайше запрещается. Тем не менее, я могу рассказать, что надо сделать, чтобы все это воспроизвести.

Comment: 1. я в посте приводил ссылку на статью. В статье есть ссылка на репозиторий. Так вот этот репозиторий для начала надо сохранить целиком и полностью на гугл-драйв.

Comment: 2. Потом надо будет скачать предварительно тренированную модель. я скачал точно такую же, как и в той статье.

Comment: 3. Потом надо будет подключиться к google Colaboratory и дальше я уже подскажу, что делать.

Comment: Eugene Dennis, я пытался отыскать условия для картинок, ничего все еще не нашел. А можно ли ссылку на эту тему? Заранее спасибо!

Comment: И.... Хорошая новость! Наконец-то вся эта моя кухня распознала и мои объекты!!!

Comment: @SeaMan75, может тогда ответите на свой собственный вопрос - здесь это приветствуется? Кроме того это может помочь другим в будущем...

Comment: Да, отвечу на свой вопрос!

Comment: Нашел такую страничку, где есть более правильный ответ на мой вопрос
: https://github.com/EdjeElectronics/TensorFlow-Object-Detection-API-Tutorial-Train-Multiple-Objects-Windows-10#3-gather-and-label-pictures

Answer (score 2):

Как оказалось, пустяковый код по ссылке [пример детектирования объектов](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-play-quidditch-using-the-tensorflow-object-detection-api-b0742b99065d) - рабочий! Только автор того кода использовал картинки для тренировки слегка расплывчатые, а я четкие. Видимо из-за этого для первого распознавания аналогичных объектов в первом случае хватило от 4000 шагов обучения, а в моем случае первое распознавание прошло **после 22 000 шагов тренировки** (поэтому я начал сомневаться, что что-то не так делаю, раз бьюсь об стену, а результата нет). В обоих случаях картинок катастрофически мало! Поэтому мне еще предстоит во многом разобраться, но самое главное, что я понял - я делаю все верно и в итоге добьюсь хороших результатов. А картинок для тренировки надо не 25 штук а несколько сотен тысяч на самом деле. И для тренировки Google colaborate не очень и подходит - в процессе бросает ошибки. Для тренировки нужны хорошие видеокарты, например, NVidia GTX 1080. В идеале - даже и 4 штуки (видеокарты должны поддерживать объединение между собой, чтобы работали, как единое целое). Для таких видеокарт нужен мощный блок питания. Это все надо для того, чтобы тренировка проходила очень быстро, чтобы не тратить месяцы на банальную тренировку. Нужны десятки гигабайт свободного места на жестком диске, нужно много оперативной памяти и очень много видеопамяти для производительности системы. 
И, если кратко, то ответ на мой вопрос: все делать, как написано в вышеприведенной ссылке и долго и упорно тренировать. Периодически проверять, как все работает
И по поводу картинок - их надо обводить рамками в программе (Windows) labelImg. Мне нужен формат PscalVOC. Так вот, оказалось, что это очень долго, тогда я сделал вот как:
1. Я изначально вырезал картинки определенного класса четко по границам и сохранял каждую в отдельном файле. Очень удобно резать картинки программой HyperSnap. Есть и другие программы, но этой получается быстрее всего вырезать прямо с экрана. 
2. Для аннотаций я написал свою собственную прожку на скорую руку. Проверил ее, поправил ошибки. Все работает. Прожка спросит, где картинки лежат (слэш в конце пути не нужен) и название класса и мгновенно сама все сделает. Обводить картинки не надо, главное, чтобы они уже изначально были нужного размера.
Прожку сделал на AHK. вот ее код (Gdip_all.ahk надо скачать дополнительно, ссылка на библиотеку внутри исходника):

```
 ; Version 1.0.0.1 
#Include Gdip_all.ahk               ; by Tic. Location: http://www.autohotkey.com/forum/topic32238.html

InputBox, path , Полный путь к папке
InputBox, objName , Название объекта на английском языке

;Loop, H:\MLDATA\New\*.png, 1
Loop, %path%\*.png, 1
{
        ;MsgBox %A_LoopFileFullPath%`n` 
        ;MsgBox %A_LoopFileName%`n
        Loop, parse, A_LoopFileFullPath, `\
    {
        If InStr(A_LoopField, ".")
            break
        else
            subfolder := A_LoopField    
    } 
    GetImageSize(A_LoopFileFullPath, width, height) 
    SetXml(A_LoopFileName, A_LoopFileFullPath, width, height, objName, subfolder)
}

Loop, %path%\*.jpg, 1
{
        Loop, parse, A_LoopFileFullPath, `\
    {
        If InStr(A_LoopField, ".")
            break
        else
            subfolder := A_LoopField    
    } 
    GetImageSize(A_LoopFileFullPath, width, height) 
    SetXml(A_LoopFileName, A_LoopFileFullPath, width, height, objName, subfolder)
}

Loop, %path%\*.jpeg, 1
{
        Loop, parse, A_LoopFileFullPath, `\
    {
        If InStr(A_LoopField, ".")
            break
        else
            subfolder := A_LoopField    
    } 
    GetImageSize(A_LoopFileFullPath, width, height) 
    SetXml(A_LoopFileName, A_LoopFileFullPath, width, height, objName, subfolder)
}

GetImageSize(ImageFullPath, ByRef w, ByRef h) {
    GDIPToken := Gdip_Startup()                             
    pBM := Gdip_CreateBitmapFromFile( ImageFullPath )                 
    W:= Gdip_GetImageWidth( pBM ), H:= Gdip_GetImageHeight( pBM )   
    Gdip_DisposeImage( pBM ), Gdip_Shutdown( GDIPToken )
    ;return w "x" h
}
```

SetXml(FileName, Folder, width, height, obj_name, subfolder)
{
    SplitPath, FileName,,,, xml_name 
    SplitPath, Folder,, xml_folder 
    ;MsgBox %xml_folder%
    ;MsgBox %xml_name%`n
    xml_file := xml_folder "\" xml_name ".xml"
    IfNotExist, %xml_file%
    {
        ;MsgBox %xml_name%`n
        FileDelete, %xml_file%
        FileAppend,`n, *%xml_file%, UTF-8
        FileAppend, %A_Tab%<folder>%subfolder%</folder>`n, *%xml_file%, UTF-8
        FileAppend, %A_Tab%%FileName%`n, *%xml_file%, UTF-8
        FileAppend, %A_Tab%<path>%Folder%</path>`n, *%xml_file%, UTF-8
        FileAppend, %A_Tab%`n, *%xml_file%, UTF-8
        FileAppend, %A_Tab%%A_Tab%<database>Unknown</database>`n, *%xml_file%, UTF-8
        FileAppend, %A_Tab%`n, *%xml_file%, UTF-8
        FileAppend, %A_Tab%<size>`n, *%xml_file%, UTF-8
        FileAppend, %A_Tab%%A_Tab%%width%`n, *%xml_file%, UTF-8
        FileAppend, %A_Tab%%A_Tab%<height>%height%</height>`n, *%xml_file%, UTF-8
        FileAppend, %A_Tab%%A_Tab%3`n, *%xml_file%, UTF-8
        FileAppend, %A_Tab%</size>`n, *%xml_file%, UTF-8
        FileAppend, %A_Tab%0`n, *%xml_file%, UTF-8
        FileAppend, %A_Tab%<object>`n, *%xml_file%, UTF-8
        FileAppend, %A_Tab%%A_Tab%%obj_name%`n, *%xml_file%, UTF-8
        FileAppend, %A_Tab%%A_Tab%<pose>Unspecified</pose>`n, *%xml_file%, UTF-8
        FileAppend, %A_Tab%%A_Tab%1`n, *%xml_file%, UTF-8
        FileAppend, %A_Tab%%A_Tab%<difficult>0</difficult>`n, *%xml_file%, UTF-8
        FileAppend, %A_Tab%%A_Tab%`n, *%xml_file%, UTF-8
        FileAppend, %A_Tab%%A_Tab%%A_Tab%<xmin>0</xmin>`n, *%xml_file%, UTF-8
        FileAppend, %A_Tab%%A_Tab%%A_Tab%0`n, *%xml_file%, UTF-8
        FileAppend, %A_Tab%%A_Tab%%A_Tab%<xmax>%width%</xmax>`n, *%xml_file%, UTF-8
        FileAppend, %A_Tab%%A_Tab%%A_Tab%%height%`n, *%xml_file%, UTF-8
        FileAppend, %A_Tab%%A_Tab%</bndbox>`n, *%xml_file%, UTF-8
        FileAppend, %A_Tab%`n, *%xml_file%, UTF-8
        FileAppend,</annotation>`n, *%xml_file%, UTF-8
    }
    else
        ;MsgBox 111

```
return
```

}